Field not getting populated when migrating
I am trying to migrate content from Drupal 7 -> Drupal 9, using Acquia Migrate:Axelerate. This is an error message I got.

[node: 189, revision: 193]: field_division_desc=This value should not
be null.||field_division_team_name_abbrev=This value should not be
null.

On the target site, it is not getting migrated, eventhough the field type is just text/integer. Why is that happening? How can I debug this?
This is the solution mentioned.

A new field was added to this entity type after entities had already
been created. This new field was marked as required, but the entities
that already existed were not updated with values for this new
required field. This is wrong in the Drupal 7 source database too,
please fix it there, refresh the source database and rollback & import
this migration!

But, in the source, the value is there.

“This is the solution mentioned”, by who? Where?

This is mentioned in solution section in Acquia Migrate Accelerate.

On further debugging, I found that there are content types, where it is failing silently. Some fields are not getting populated at all.
